# Sencha touch2: Ajax Post request success and failure function not getting called?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch2, I have proxy with Ajax Post Request and am able to get Json data. but my success and failure functions are not getting called ? Any idea how can I do that? 
Here is my model for your reference:

```
Ext.define('TestApp.model.ModelList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype:'modelList',
    config: {
        fields:['work'],

        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            method: 'POST',

            url:'http://localhost:9090/apps/works',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            actionMethods: {
                create : 'POST',
                read   : 'POST', // by default GET
                update : 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
                'Accept':'application/json'

            },
            callback: function(options, success, response) {
                console.log('999999999'+response.responseText);// not getting called
            },
            success: function(response) {
              console.log('success++++');// not getting called
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                console.log('failure++++');// not getting called
            },

            reader:
            {
                type:'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use Chrome Developer Tools. Open the Network tab. Reload your page or fire your request. Look at the network traffic. What happens?

Comment: What does the server return?

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy itself does not define callbacks.
The operation performed does. So for example `Model.load(1,{...})` can specify the callback function in the config params like this:

```
MyApp.User.load(10, {
    scope: this,
    failure: function(record, operation) {
        //do something if the load failed
    },
    success: function(record, operation) {
        //do something if the load succeeded
    },
    callback: function(record, operation) {
        //do something whether the load succeeded or failed
    }
});
```

more info here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model 
or here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load

Also make sure you that you need Ajax proxy and not JSONP proxy. on Ajax proxy usually you do not need to specify host and port as it should be the same as the app host. If thats not the case then you need JSONP proxy.

Comment: Can you please help me out where can i write the above code ?